# No setPadding programmatically for TableRow?

Tags: android, dynamic, padding, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm such new in Android and I would like to setPadding programmatically for a TableRow, I can have in my layout :

```
<TableRow
    android:padding="15dp" >
```

It looks that the Margin can be setted programmatically by **setMargin** however it looks that programmatically the TableRow object doesn't have a **setPadding** Method... Is there any method to set a padding to a tableRow programmatically ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) class, as with all [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) subclasses, indeed has a [setPadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method.

However, since you mention that you found `setMargin`, I believe you are looking at the [TableRow.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html) instead of the `TableRow` itself.

Margins are set in a View's `LayoutParams`, whereas padding is set on the `View`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the TableRow object doesn't have a setMargin method. You can set margin to view via LayoutParams,as shown in the code below:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
params.setMargins(left,top,right,down);
tv1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You can set padding for TableRow directly:

```
view.setPadding(left,top,right,down);
```